# passing array/object in $.POST

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post

I have following code javascript:

```
var configuration = [];

configuration["step 1"] = val1;
configuration["step 2"] = val2;
configuration["step 3"] = val3;
configuration["extraData"] = extra_data;        

var data = {
    action: 'configuration_save',
    config: configuration,
};

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    alert(response)
});
```

`$_POST['config']` in PHP shows empty. Am I am doing any mistake while passing array.

**PHP CODE**

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;

add_user_meta( $user_id, "CONFIG", $_POST['config']);
```

Comment: remove the `,` here `config: configuration,`

Comment: show us `configuration_save` code

Comment: @TheFlash : still empty

Comment: I want to see what you do with the data after it has been posted - please show that code

Comment: Declare the new associative array like this, `var configuration = {};`

Comment: @CapitalC : still empty

Comment: try with integer index

Comment: JavaScript part should be fine after changing your array to {} style. Now is to troubleshoot the server part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below updated one

```
    var main_configuration = [] ;
    var configuration = [];
    var configuration ={
           'step 1' :  val1,
           'step 2' :  val2,
           'step 3' : val3,
           'extraData' : extra_data
    };

    main_configuration.push(configuration);

    var data = {
            action: 'configuration_save',
            config: main_configuration,

            };
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {

                alert(response)

    });
```

Comment: why should I use like that ? I want everything in one array

Comment: JavaScript treat `[]` and `{}` differently. 1st one is only for numbered array, 2nd one (object style) only can have string keys.

Comment: then use  configuration.push({"step 1": val1}); and so on it will work

Comment: @Kool-Mind works without your main_configuration. Can you tell me why it was not working . and when do we need to parse the array or when do we require to use json_encode , decode

Comment: @CapitalC : so array cannot  have string keys ??

Comment: My statement is just based on trial. If we consider [] is array, and {} is object, then "YES". You can't have something like this: ["key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"].